# How to check if an element is in a sub list, then print the sub list

Tags: python, list, sublist

My program requires the user to input a keyword just like below:

```
search = input("Enter data name: ").upper()

    with open('schedule.txt', 'r') as f:
        list_of_lists = []
        for line in f:
            stripped_line = line.strip()
            line_list = stripped_line.split(',')
            list_of_lists.append(line_list)
        print(list_of_lists)
        for lists in list_of_lists:
            if search in lists:
                output = lists
                print('The available flights are:', *output, sep='\n')
            else:
                print('No flights found')
        f.close()
```

If the keyword is present in the sublist, then my program will print that sublist (Could be found in more than one sublist, so several outputs are expected). The problem i have right now is, however, the output does not checkk for the element and it displayed in a long as list instead of separating in a new line.

My text file:

```
[1] MH371, MALAYSIAN AIRLINE, KUALA LUMPUR, BEIJING , 19-12-2021, N/A
[2] SX849, AIRASIA          , KUALA LUMPUR, BANGKOK , 05-01-2022, N/A
[3] MH234, MALAYSIAN AIRLINE, KUALA LUMPUR, LANGKAWI, 03-02-2022, N/A
[4] FD709, KOREA AIRLINE    , KUALA LUMPUR, SEOUL   , 29-12-2021, N/A
[5] Z1314, CATHAY AIRLINE   , KUALA LUMPUR, TOKYO   , 21-01-2022, N/A
[6] HY520, EMIRATES         , KUALA LUMPUR, TAIPEI  , 15-11-2021, N/A
[7] TT879, MALINDO AIR      , KUALA LUMPUR, HAWAII  , 08-02-2022, N/A
```

My output:

```
Enter data name: bangkok
[['[1] MH371', ' MALAYSIAN AIRLINE', ' KUALA LUMPUR', ' BEIJING ', ' 19-12-2021', ' N/A'], ['[2] SX849', ' AIRASIA          ', ' KUALA LUMPUR', ' BANGKOK ', ' 05-01-2022', ' N/A'], ['[3] MH234', ' MALAYSIAN AIRLINE', ' KUALA LUMPUR', ' LANGKAWI', ' 03-02-2022', ' N/A'], ['[4] FD709', ' KOREA AIRLINE    ', ' KUALA LUMPUR', ' SEOUL   ', ' 29-12-2021', ' N/A'], ['[5] Z1314', ' CATHAY AIRLINE   ', ' KUALA LUMPUR', ' TOKYO   ', ' 21-01-2022', ' N/A'], ['[6] HY520', ' EMIRATES         ', ' KUALA LUMPUR', ' TAIPEI  ', ' 15-11-2021', ' N/A'], ['[7] TT879', ' MALINDO AIR      ', ' KUALA LUMPUR', ' HAWAII  ', ' 08-02-2022', ' N/A']]
```

As you can see, it prints entire list instead of just the sub list where the element is present

Comment: You code doesn't work because your fields are not stripped: `' BANGKOK '` is not equal to `'BANGKOK'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the correct answer as been pointed out by @Jab already, I'll correct your mistake so that it helps with your homework assignment

*In your code from line 9 to line 13:*

```
for lists in list_of_lists:
    if search in lists:
        output = lists
        print('The available flights are:', *output, sep='\n')
```

*lists variable will be equal to :*

```
[1] MH371, MALAYSIAN AIRLINE, KUALA LUMPUR, BEIJING , 19-12-2021, N/A
```

in the first run and your really searching for the list of strings instead of just a string like "KUALA LUMPUR"

So, to correct that you can use 2 loops instead of one to access the inner elements.

*like this :*

```
for lists in list_of_lists:
        for elements in lists:
            if search in elements:  
                output = lists
                print('The available flights are: \n', *output, sep='')
```

Comment: @halfer Is it wrong ask for an upvote so that the correct answers stays on top
(it helps others with similar questions)

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. Please don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can see if the word is in the line then convert it to a list and output:

```
search = input("Enter data name: ").upper()

with open('filename.csv') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        sublist = list(map(str.strip, line.split(',')))
        if search in sublist:
            print(sublist)
```

Output:

```
>>> Enter data name: bangkok
['[2] SX849', 'AIRASIA', 'KUALA LUMPUR', 'BANGKOK', '05-01-2022', 'N/A']
```

Comment: This might have unexpected effects if the searched string is a substring of another field ;) (+1 though)

Comment: OP said "If the keyword is present in sublist" which is vague considering the rest of the question. Although I will edit.

Comment: I think OP probably meant `['WORD', 'OTHER']` should be matched by `WORD` but not `OR`